# Creating predefined values in field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, values

I would like to make programmatically (with Python) the same thing than we can do directly in QGIS when you create a list of values for a field.

I would like to create a new field and specify a list of possible values for this field. I didn't find any function for that in the API. Is there anyone who has the solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to assign and configure a `ValueMap` widget to your layer's field in this way:

### QGIS 3.x

```
fieldIndex = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'myField' )
editor_widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup( 'ValueMap', {
                         'map': {'Description 1': 'value1', 
                                 'Description 2': 'value2'}
                        }
                      )
layer.setEditorWidgetSetup( fieldIndex, editor_widget_setup )
```

### QGIS 2.x

```
fieldIndex = layer.fieldNameIndex( 'myField' )
layer.setEditorWidgetV2( fieldIndex, 'ValueMap' )
values = {u'Description 1': u'value1', 
          u'Description 2': u'value2', 
          u'Description 3': u'value3'}
layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config( fieldIndex, values )
```

Comment: `setEditorWidgetV2Config(...)` works, but I get a deprecation warning, are there other approaches?

Comment: Added a note showing how to configure Value Maps for QGIS3.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo is there a way to set a function from `.qgis2\python\expressions` instead of value1 ?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple selection option with map value ?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need to use Value Relation for that.