# Adding predefined values in exact order for value map field in PyQGIS and add empty field?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a problem with predefined values and their order in 'value map' field. Wnen I tried this [Creating predefined values in field using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230555/how-to-create-predefined-values-in-a-field-in-pyqgis) it works, but I'm not able to keep order (even when I use OrderedDict instead of dict).
The second problem is how to insert also empty value.

```
    val_map = OrderedDict()
    for value,label in sorted(val['values'].items()):
        val_map[label.decode("utf-8")] = label.decode("utf-8")
    print(val_map)
    vlayer.setEditorWidgetV2( index, 'ValueMap' )
    vlayer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(index, val_map)
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([(u'silnice I.t\u0159', u'silnice I.t\u0159'), (u'silnice II.t\u0159', u'silnice II.t\u0159'), (u'silnice III.t\u0159', u'silnice III.t\u0159'), (u'MK I.t\u0159', u'MK I.t\u0159'), (u'MK II.t\u0159', u'MK II.t\u0159'), (u'MK III.t\u0159', u'MK III.t\u0159'), (u'MK IV.t\u0159', u'MK IV.t\u0159'), (u'UK', u'UK')])
```

But you can see, that there is alphabetical order in value map
[image]

Comment: Did you try your OrderedDict.keys() and orderedDict.values()? It would be good if you post the code that didn't work for you so that we know what went wrong.